# Can I use multiple threads to reduce the time taken to encrypt a large file?

Tags: multithreading, performance, encryption

I want to reduce the encryption time of large file. Can I use multi-threading to reduce this time?

Answer (score 1):

Most encryption algorithms have encryption state that depends on the previously encrypted data, so for these algorithms, the answer is no. You would have to create your own scheme.

Comment: what about AES-128 encryption algo?

Comment: @user10776 AES-128 itself can only encrypt 16 bytes, no more no less. For other sizes you need a mode of encryption. Some modes are parallelizable, some are not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But not all encryption schemes can be parallel.

If you prefer block ciphers, such as AES or DES, [CTR mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) if often chosen.

On the other hand, for stream ciphers, [Salsa20](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) and its family are designed to be parallel. Therefore they are fast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can,

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29

Exact implementation details will vary depending on your platform